# HTML button causes all JS functions to be undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add the line for a button to enable a clock in HTML and add the respected function in a `<script>` tag (which may or may not work by the way), then all functions on that page are now undefined. I only have one other function on that page, so it could just be that. I've looked for a while for syntax issues but I can't find anything.

JavaScript, then CSS, then HTML for the page.

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
```

```css
.headtitle {
 color:red;
 font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 border: 5px solid #00f;
 padding: 10px;
}
.subtitle{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 font-size: 1.25rem
}
a.firstlink{
 word-spacing: 30px;
}
a:visited{
 color:lightblue
}
body{
 background-image: url("http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/a942qcqwrcmveiq37zli.png");
 background-repeat:repeat;
 color: white;
}
.list{
 display: inline;
}
.list li{
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
.button{
 float:right;
 border: 1px solid #f00;
 padding: 5px
}
.button:active{
 position: relative;
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
}
.JavascriptButton{
 float:right;
}
.clickText{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Website task.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="new 1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function openFunction() {
    window.open('Website Task.html', '_blank');
   }
   function showTime() {
    document.getElementByID("currentTime").innerhtml = "The time is now" startTime();
   }
  </script>
  <title>Javascript page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <h1 class="headtitle">Javascript demo page</h1>
   <p class="subtitle">This page is for demonstrating functions in Javascript in particular, as well as jQuery.</p>
   <p id="currentTime"></p>
   <button onclick="showTime()">Click here to show the time</button>
   <p></p>
   <a class="clickText" onclick="openFunction()">Click this text to return to the previous page in a new window</a>
   <button class="JavascriptButton" onclick="window.location='Website Task.html';">Previous page</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open the Console of your browser's developer tools. Read the error message.

Comment: There seem to be many things wrong with your code, such as the in-existance of the element with the id of "txt", also the typo in your showTime function (getElementbyID -> getElementById) as well as your onclick function with the window.location...

Comment: It just says '"showTime()" is undefined' when I click on the button. And it looks to me that getElementByID looks normal, RugDealer

Comment: There is a typo in the `showTime()` function. Two actually, the spelling of `innerhtml` and a missing plus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have syntax errors in your code. Simply open dev tools to find this out...

```
document.getElementById("currentTime").innerhtml = "The time is now" startTime();
```

=> `"the time is now " + startTime();`

but your startTime function doesn't return anything so it's useless like that

Comment: Yes, that solves the undefined issue but now "
Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByID'" on the document.getElementByID. I would suppose this means that I can't use the element I have selected to do what I want?

Comment: @JackRaiden — No, it means that you got the name of the function wrong.